# Trying to avoid switch or if with a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to render appropriate videos when a button is clicked. I could do it in a switch or an if, but it would mean doing a lot of changes in the future.

Anyone has an idea how to optimize it?

```
var Commercial = ["foNU8cPCaws", '7sZUZePLR-c', 'CrrSAc-vjG4', 'eaiGUVNZmD8'];
var Documentary = ["UcQ4IcnZYUI", 'ORUoFcxJAb0', 'HRkm3javGfo', 'f5jyYqXmnhQ'];
var isFirstPass = true;

$('.category-button').on('click', function () {
 var $channelName = $(this).closest('div').prev('h2').text();
  showVideos($channelName);
});

function showVideos(channelName) {
  if (!isFirstPass) {
    $('#addedContent').remove();
  }

  $('#dropdownVideoPicker').append('<div id="addedContent"></div>');

  for (var i = 0; i < channelName.length; i++) {
    $('#addedContent').append(generatePageCode(channelName[i]));
  }

  isFirstPass = false;

  $('.videoThumbnail').on('click', function () {
    grabYtId();
  });
}

function grabYtId() {
  console.log($(this).attr('src').slice(27, -6));
}
```

What I'm trying to do is: When the user clicks a button, the button goes to its parent's sibling, h2, and calls a function, giving it an array called the same as the h2.text() value

Example with HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 category-shape">
  <div class="inside-category col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <img style="margin-top:30px;" src="Assets/Images/Icons/commercial.png" alt="commercial" />
    </div>
    <h2 class="col-md-12 text-center category-title">Commercial </h2>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foNU8cPCaws&list=PLR1n4Pmhcag6H73FvubwoZUEkcf92Mr11">
        <button id="commercialButton" type="button" class="btn category-button">
          See The Videos
        </button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically I want to avoid this:

```
switch ($channelName) {
  case "Commercial":
    showVideos(Documentary);
    break;
  case "Documentary":
    showVideos(Documentary);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use an object for this, e.g.

```
const videoIds = {
  documentary: ['UcQ4IcnZYUI', 'ORUoFcxJAb0', 'HRkm3javGfo', 'f5jyYqXmnhQ'],
  commercial: ['foNU8cPCaws', '7sZUZePLR-c', 'CrrSAc-vjG4', 'eaiGUVNZmD8']
};
```

Then based on which option you need, just select it with the matching key: `videoIds.documentary`, `videoIds.commercial`, etc.

If you try accessing a key that isn't in the object, its value is just returned as `undefined`.

Comment: So I'd be sending a full object every time?